# Calculating how many bolts are needed to hold parts

Tags: pressure, bolting, bending

Suppose we have a stack of thin metal sheets, layered on top of each other. Let's say 20 sheets, 0.2mm thick, and each sheet is 70mm by 70mm.
Let's also say that the sheets are not totally flat, so when they are stacked together, each sheet does not sit totally flush against the sheet above and below. This is a problem, and it is desirable to make the sheets lay totally flat, with all of a sheet’s surface touching the sheets above and below.

The sheets have holes in them. Bolts are put through the holes, and nuts are tightened around the bolts, clamping the sheets together between force applied to the top and bottom of the stack. Using the torque and the bolt diameter, it is possible to calculate the clamping force of the bolt
[clamp force calculator](https://calculator.academy/clamping-force-calculator/#f1p1)

If the goal is to use the clamping force of the bolts and nuts to compress the stack so that every part of the sheets' surface is pressed flush against the sheets above and below, how might we determine the required number of holes/bolts given a bolt diameter of 2mm?

Comment: This is going to be extremely highly dependent on how far out of flat the sheets are.  I don't think the question is answerable as currently stated.

Comment: Bent in multiple directions or one nice curve?

Comment: "totally flat" is not a specification, and this question can't really be answered as given.